Proxmox 7 - Randomly removing DHCP data
I run a Proxmox 7 instance (non-enterprise), and randomly, ip a shows no address, and I can't reach the outside network, and the outside network can't access it. If I use dhclient, it fixes it, but why is this happening? It happens about every hour.
Inxi -F:
System:
  Host: [REDACTED] Kernel: 5.15.102-1-pve x86_64 bits: 64 Console: tty 1 
  Distro: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) 
Machine:
  Type: Desktop System: Dell product: XPS 8940 v: N/A serial: 7J433Q3 
  Mobo: Dell model: 0K3CM7 v: A00 serial: [REDACTED]
  UEFI: Dell v: 2.10.0 date: 09/14/2022 
CPU:
  Info: 8-Core model: 11th Gen Intel Core i7-11700 bits: 64 type: MT MCP 
  L2 cache: 16 MiB 
  Speed: 3341 MHz min/max: 800/4800 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 3341 2: 4755 
  3: 4658 4: 4814 5: 4800 6: 4800 7: 4757 8: 4799 9: 4820 10: 4726 11: 4807 
  12: 4803 13: 4808 14: 4803 15: 4800 16: 4800 
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel driver: i915 v: kernel 
  Device-2: NVIDIA driver: nouveau v: kernel 
  Display: server: No display server data found. Headless machine? tty: N/A 
  Message: Advanced graphics data unavailable in console for root. 
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel driver: snd_hda_intel 
  Device-2: NVIDIA driver: snd_hda_intel 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.15.102-1-pve 
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Comet Lake PCH CNVi WiFi driver: iwlwifi 
  IF: wlo1 state: down mac: 00:93:37:45:7d:ce 
  Device-2: Realtek driver: r8169 
  IF: enp4s0 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: b0:4f:13:16:ca:11 
  IF-ID-1: bonding_masters state: N/A speed: N/A duplex: N/A mac: N/A 
  IF-ID-2: docker0 state: down mac: 02:42:b1:bd:4a:c6 
  IF-ID-3: fwbr102i0 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: unknown 
  mac: 46:d1:ac:a2:b1:74 
  IF-ID-4: fwln102i0 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full 
  mac: 22:24:b6:b6:10:79 
  IF-ID-5: fwpr102p0 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full 
  mac: aa:70:fd:67:70:f0 
  IF-ID-6: veth102i0 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full 
  mac: fe:81:a0:7d:05:d0 
  IF-ID-7: vmbr0 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: unknown 
  mac: b0:4f:13:16:ca:11 
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Intel type: USB driver: btusb 
  Message: Required tool hciconfig not installed. Check --recommends 
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 3.19 TiB used: 35.84 GiB (1.1%) 
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Samsung model: PM991a NVMe 512GB 
  size: 476.94 GiB 
  ID-2: /dev/sda vendor: Seagate model: ST1000DM010-2EP102 size: 931.51 GiB 
  ID-3: /dev/sdb vendor: Samsung model: SSD 870 EVO 2TB size: 1.82 TiB 
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 93.93 GiB used: 35.84 GiB (38.1%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/dm-1 
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 1022 MiB used: 356 KiB (0.0%) fs: vfat 
  dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2 
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: partition size: 8 GiB used: 6.2 MiB (0.1%) 
  dev: /dev/dm-0 
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 43.0 C mobo: N/A 
  Fan Speeds (RPM): cpu: 808 fan-2: 0 
Info:
  Processes: 347 Uptime: 6h 21m Memory: 46.63 GiB used: 2.27 GiB (4.9%) 
  Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Shell: Bash inxi: 3.3.01


You're assigning an address via DHCP to the the virtualization host?
How you even ended up like that? Installer and GUI wouldn't allow you to do that. Have you edited a configuration manually, or installed PVE on top of Debian? Then you haven't followed the installation manual:

configure a static IP

Assign a static address and fix /etc/hosts accordingly. That is a requirement.
Then consider upgrading to Proxmox VE 8.

I used 7 because the 8 installer didn't work, and DHCP was allowed. My router's assigned IPs are based on the MAC address of the device, they aren't random.

And I didn't even realize that there was an installation guide.
